# list operation in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have two Lists

```
ListA ={'a','b','c','d','e'};
ListB ={'a','c','d','f'}
```

I need the `ListC` from `ListA` and `ListB`, such that `ListC= {'b','e'}`

Is that possible and how to get that `ListC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ListA = new List<char> { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
var ListB = new List<char> { 'a', 'c', 'd', 'f' };
var ListC = ListA.Except(ListB).ToList();
// ^^ has 2 items; 'b' and 'c'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer ,initially i tried remove in foreach loop but that is an error.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Except` method:

```
var result = ListA.Except(ListB);
//result: b, e
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
var ListC = ListA.Except(ListB).ToList();
```

You can translate it with: "give me all from first that's not in second"

If you instead want the opposite: "give me all from first that's also in second" use [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx):

```
var ListC = ListA.Intersect(ListB);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var listC = listA.Except(listB).ToList();
```

Comment: no, that isn't an intersection (or wasn't; now edited correctly)